# Why does volley encrypt my post-request without telling it so

Tags: java, android, https, android-volley

I am trying to login to a remote address which uses https.
For this I use volley to send a post-request with my user data.

This is my relevant code (`includes setting up a StringRequest -> fire StringRequest`):

```
StringRequest myStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, remoteurl, this, this) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Accept-Charset","utf-8");
                headers.put("Connection","keep-alive");
                headers.put("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0");
                headers.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name","myname");
                params.put("pw","mypw");
                params.put("totp","");
                params.put("app","76");
                return params;
            }
        };
SingleTonVolley.getInstance().getRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).add(myStringRequest);
```

Where my SingleTon for instantiating a `newRequestQueue` looks the following:

```
public class SingleTonVolley {
private static SingleTonVolley mInstance = new SingleTonVolley();
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

private SingleTonVolley() {
}

public static SingleTonVolley getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public synchronized RequestQueue getRequestQueue(Context context) {
    if(mRequestQueue == null)
    {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}
```

}

However when running my code I can see with `WireShark` that my data is sent encrypted using `TLSv1.2`:

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
 11 2.898033000    192.168.0.19          80.190.158.9          TCP      74     57186 > https [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=11207479 TSecr=0 WS=128
 12 2.929011000    80.190.158.9          192.168.0.19          TCP      74     https > 57186 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14480 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=210621220 TSecr=11207479 WS=128
 13 2.929044000    192.168.0.19          80.190.158.9          TCP      66     57186 > https [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29312 Len=0 TSval=11207487 TSecr=210621220
 14 2.930506000    192.168.0.19          80.190.158.9          TLSv1.2  284    Client Hello
 15 2.959979000    80.190.158.9          192.168.0.19          TCP      66     https > 57186 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=219 Win=15616 Len=0 TSval=210621228 TSecr=11207487
 16 2.964700000    80.190.158.9          192.168.0.19          TLSv1.2  1514   Server Hello
 17 2.964742000    192.168.0.19          80.190.158.9          TCP      66     57186 > https [ACK] Seq=219 Ack=1449 Win=32128 Len=0 TSval=11207496 TSecr=210621229
 18 2.967946000    80.190.158.9          192.168.0.19          TLSv1.2  1725   Certificate
 19 2.967997000    192.168.0.19          80.190.158.9          TCP      66     57186 > https [ACK] Seq=219 Ack=3108 Win=35456 Len=0 TSval=11207496 TSecr=210621229
 20 2.993710000    192.168.0.19          80.190.158.9          TLSv1.2  192    Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
 21 3.027476000    80.190.158.9          192.168.0.19          TLSv1.2  324    New Session Ticket, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
 22 3.030701000    192.168.0.19          80.190.158.9          TLSv1.2  471    Application Data
 23 3.107383000    80.190.158.9          192.168.0.19          TCP      66     https > 57186 [ACK] Seq=3366 Ack=750 Win=16640 Len=0 TSval=210621265 TSecr=11207512
 35 3.194115000    80.190.158.9          192.168.0.19          TCP      1514   [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
 36 3.195622000    80.190.158.9          192.168.0.19          TLSv1.2  6488   Application Data
 37 3.195653000    192.168.0.19          80.190.158.9          TCP      66     57186 > https [ACK] Seq=750 Ack=11236 Win=54144 Len=0 TSval=11207553 TSecr=210621286
535 63.283062000   80.190.158.9          192.168.0.19          TLSv1.2  97     Encrypted Alert
536 63.283534000   80.190.158.9          192.168.0.19          TCP      66     https > 57186 [FIN, ACK] Seq=11267 Ack=750 Win=16640 Len=0 TSval=210636286 TSecr=11207553
537 63.320615000   192.168.0.19          80.190.158.9          TCP      66     57186 > https [ACK] Seq=750 Ack=11268 Win=54144 Len=0 TSval=11222585 TSecr=210636286
```

Regarding to many other questions on `SO` I can see that everyone have to pass an `SSLSocketFactory` when creating `newRequestQueue`. However while this sounds absolutely logically to me, I wonder why my program does this by default as I did not add any `SSLSocketFactory`. I wonder if I have a newer version of volley than the other user used when asking the question on SO in the past. However when looking at the [source-code of volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/2f9a77c9ec313fd09eb831c606069f748213f67c/src/main/java/com/android/volley) I was not able to find any detection when using a `https-url` that automatically assigns a `SSLSocketFactory` to the `RequestQueue`.
Hope somebody can bring some light in my issue.

**Addition**

Only `SSLSocketFactory` relevant stuff I could find was in `HurlStack.class`:

**Constructor:**

```
public HurlStack(UrlRewriter urlRewriter, SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory) {
    mUrlRewriter = urlRewriter;
    mSslSocketFactory = sslSocketFactory;
}
```

**Evaluation if SSLSocketFactory was passed:**

```
    // use caller-provided custom SslSocketFactory, if any, for HTTPS
    if ("https".equals(url.getProtocol()) && mSslSocketFactory != null) {
        ((HttpsURLConnection)connection).setSSLSocketFactory(mSslSocketFactory);
    }
```

So `"https".equals(url.getProtocol())` will evaluate to true in my case but `mSslSocketFactory != null` will not!

Comment: got any answer for that so far?

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't have anything got do with the socket factory. You have specified `HTTPS`, you got `HTTPS`.

Comment: By specified you mean because I provided a https address? If so, who is it that delivers me https because I specified it? the OS, volley or something else? Can you be more precise please with this answer I does not know more than I did before asking...